# PostGIS & Geoserver Missing Layers

Tags: postgis, geoserver

Currently pretty new to webmapping, I have created a PostGIS Database with OS Mastermap (OSMM) Data for Herefordshire (UK County). I have accsess and used these layers within QGIS so the database appears to be setup correctly.

I have successfully connected to the database within Geoservers web admin and been able to add other small vector layers with no problem. The OSMM layer currently don't show up as an option when I try to add them. Any ideas? File size perhaps?

I should mention this is currently setup on localhost.

Comment: OSMM works fine in GeoServer so not a size issue - how did you add them

Comment: Please describe what you mean by “when I try to add them”. I assume you are trying to create a datastore and then create a layer out of it. Was the datastore creation OK? If yes, was the layer creation OK? If yes, can you see a preview with the Layer Preview panel?

Comment: Appllogises for being unclear this is quite new to me, the OSMM data has been added to the PostGIS database and as a store on Geoserver when I attempt to add them as a Layer on Geoserver they don't appear as an option but I am sure they are in the database as I have opened it within QGIS